# execute code when tomcat server turns on

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, service, reset

I wonder if you could help me with this:

At first sorry if I am asking something easy, but I am amateur in this.

I have a tomcat server in my computer and I have several services (programmed in java language with Eclipse) in it. What I would like to know is if it is possible to stablish a code that should be execute in each service when Tomcat server turns on or reset. If it is possible, how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [`ServletContextListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContextListener.html) is meant for exactly this type of thing. Your implementation of `contextInitialized()` will be called when the server starts the "context" (meaning the webapp).

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Context Creation listener.(ServletContextListener)